# Render Date Range on node template

Tags: theming, entities, datetime

I'm trying to render both start and end date on a node template in Drupal 8 from the Date range field from the content type. I've tried multiple ways to no avail.

-- Only shows start date --

```
{{ kint(node.field_date_range.value ) }} 

{% if node.field_date_range %}
{{ node.field_date_range.value|date(format='l M j') }}
{% endif %}
```

---

Comment: This works: {{ node.field_date_range.value|date(format='l M j') ~ ' thru ' ~ node.field_date_range.end_value|date(format='l M j') }}

Comment: Why do you need to render the field directly instead of using the formatters?

Comment: Your first comment claims you have found a solution: you should post it as an update in the original question, so people will able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the full solution that allowed me to separate the content into a traditional calendar mock-up on a node--events--html.twig:

```
<div class="cal-wrapper">

{% if node.field_date_range.value %}
  <div class="cal-day">
  {{ node.field_date_range.value|date(format='l')  ~ ' thru ' ~ node.field_date_end_range_value|date(format='l') }}
{% else %}
  {{ node.field_date.value|date(format='l') }}
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% if node.field_date_range.value %}
  <div class="cal-month">
  {{ node.field_date_range.value|date(format='M')  ~ ' thru ' ~ node.field_date_end_range_value|date(format='M') }}
 {% else %}
  {{ node.field_date.value|date(format='M') }}
 </div>
 {% endif %}

 {% if node.field_date_range.value %}
   <div class="cal-main-date">
   {{ node.field_date_range.value|date(format='j')  ~ ' thru ' ~ node.field_date_end_range_value|date(format='j') }}
 {% else %}
   {{ node.field_date.value|date(format='j') }}
   </div>
 {% endif %}

 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the end value of a *'data_range'* field you can use: *'.end_value'*, instead of *'.value'*, example:

```
{% if node.field_date_range %}
  {{ node.field_date_range.end_value|date(format='l M j') }}
{% endif %}
```

Sorry my bad english.